# How to change the attribute table popup/hover text in a plotly map

Tags: r, ggplot2, hover, tooltip, r-plotly

I am trying to make an interactive [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) map from a shapefile, with a hover/tooltip that shows some information.

Currently when I hover over an area on the map it only gives the information for `VAR1` (A,B,C,D) rather than the information in `DATA$HOVER`

The map (Called `NUTS1` in my code) is obtained from: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/nuts-level-1-january-2018-full-clipped-boundaries-in-the-united-kingdom)

I do not have access to SF.

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.4.0 Patched (2017-05-31 r72750)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>   packageVersion("plotly")
>   [1] ‘4.7.1’ 
>   packageVersion("ggplot2")
>   [1] ‘2.2.1’

```
DATA <- c(NA)
DATA$NUTS1 <- c("UKC","UKD","UKE","UKF","UKG","UKH","UKI","UKJ","UKK","UKL","UKM",
"UKN")
DATA$VAR1  <- c("D","D","A","D","A","C","B","C","B","C","B","A")
DATA$VAR2  <- c("8","4","1","10","4","7","5","1","8","6","3","8")
DATA$VAR3  <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")
NUTS1 <- readOGR(dsn = 
          "NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom",
                 layer = 
          "NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom")
NUTS1 <- fortify(NUTS1, region = "nuts118cd")
DATA$HOVER <- with(DATA, paste(NUTS1, "<br>", VAR1, "<br>", VAR2, "<br>", VAR3))

p <- ggplot(data = DATA, text = HOVER) + 
  geom_map(data = DATA, aes(map_id = NUTS1, fill = VAR1), map = NUTS1) + 
  expand_limits(x = NUTS1$long, y = NUTS1$lat)

p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, first of all, your `DATA` object should be a `data.frame` (from your code I get a list, which is no accepted by the `ggplot()` function).

Then, try to map the column `HOVER` into the `text` aesthetic in `geom_map()` and not in `ggplot()`.

Also, in your `DATA` data.frame, rename the column `NUTS1` to `id`, so that it matches the column name `id` from `NUTS1` data.frame obtained with `fortify` (you see that this is important from the examples found in `help(geom_map)`).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(rgdal)

DATA <- data.frame(id = c("UKC","UKD","UKE","UKF","UKG","UKH","UKI","UKJ","UKK","UKL","UKM","UKN"),
                   VAR1 = c("D","D","A","D","A","C","B","C","B","C","B","A"),
                   VAR2 = c("8","4","1","10","4","7","5","1","8","6","3","8"),
                   VAR3 = 1:12)
DATA$HOVER <- with(DATA, paste(id, "<br>", VAR1, "<br>", VAR2, "<br>", VAR3))

NUTS1 <- readOGR(dsn = "NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom",
                 layer = "NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom")
NUTS1 <- fortify(NUTS1, region = "nuts118cd")

p <- ggplot(data = DATA) + 
  geom_map(aes(map_id = id, fill = VAR1, text = HOVER), map = NUTS1) +
  expand_limits(x = NUTS1$long, y = NUTS1$lat)

p2 <- ggplotly(p)
p2
```

[image]

---

Note that, interactive maps are more straightforward to make with the [`mapview` package](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/index.html). For your particular issue, check [mapview popups](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_04-popups.html). Here is an attempt with `mapview`:

```
library(mapview)
library(rgdal)

NUTS1 <- readOGR(dsn = "NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom",
                 layer = "NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Clipped_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom")

DATA <- data.frame(NUTS1 = c("UKC","UKD","UKE","UKF","UKG","UKH","UKI","UKJ","UKK","UKL","UKM","UKN"),
                   VAR1 = c("D","D","A","D","A","C","B","C","B","C","B","A"),
                   VAR2 = c("8","4","1","10","4","7","5","1","8","6","3","8"),
                   VAR3 = 1:12)
# merge DATA with the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame NUTS1
nuts <- merge(x = NUTS1, y = DATA, by.x = "nuts118cd", by.y = "NUTS1")

mapview(nuts, popup = popupTable(nuts, zcol = c("nuts118cd", "VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3")))
```

[image]

To fill by `VAR1`, you need to follow [this example](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_02-advanced.html#multiple-layers) and call `zcol = "VAR1"` in `mapview`, like:

```
mapview(nuts, zcol = "VAR1", 
        popup = popupTable(nuts, zcol = c("nuts118cd", "VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3")))
```